# Como creo un script referenciador, ejemplo cdn

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, php7

tengo un chat bot montado en un servidor gratuito, es solo el icono en la parte derecha, cuando le doy click abre el chat, quiero tratar de crear un script que al crear un html limpio que no contenga nada en el body, yo coloque ese script y al ejecutar el html me traiga el bot igualito como en el servidor, en una empresa que yo trabaje se hacia un chat web y en un html se pegaba un script y traia el chat, solo que no se como se realiza ese proceso, pero lo traían con unscript. como podria realizarse algo asi? es como un tipo cdn parecido.

Comment: imagino que tienes el servidor con el payload desde una funcion que retorna cuando haces click, para no estar imaginando es bueno que solucionemos el problema cuando copies el codigo por favor, edita tu pregunta, coloca el codigo que corresponde al payload o json que tienes en un server, para que podamos indagar hasta que punto es necesario darle los atributos correspondiente con el html. y luego el javascript

Comment: en si es un modal que al darle clik me abre un cuadrito de conversacion, lo que nececito es como referencio esa url del servidor , en un html en blanco , con un script, pero la verdad no se si obligatoriamente se nececita un cdn, o existira otra manera de referenciar ese pagina en un nuevo html el cual solo con el link cargue la misma pagina del servidor

Comment: Bueno en principio lo que tienes que hacer es que todos los elementos que tienes donde se muestra la ventana del chat se rendericen, se muestre al hacer click en algun modal. luego los elementos que estan en el html oculto no necesitan ser renderizados desde ningun cdn si ya esta el servidor en un archivo de javascript o archivo de un servidor de websocket por ejemplo.


fijate de la siguiente respuesta que voya colocar en la sección de respuesta para darle formato al codigo esta bien?

Answer (score 0):

tenemos que usar dos secciones para poder hacer posible que funcione.

primero. tenemos un html al que se va a estar mostrando siempre que es la ventana flotando en todo el sitio web ese seria el elemento principal que va a llamar a la ventana del chat. de la siguiente manera

```css
     display: none;   // por defecto esta oculto 
                }
               .mostrarElemento {
                  display: block;
                }
                .ElementoFlotante {
                    display: fix; // siempre esta mostrando el elemento en una posición fixed
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    border-raidus: ;
                }
```

````html
  <div class="ElementoFlotante" > 
             ``` Html que se mostrará para darle estilos al elemento cuadrito que quieres mostrar dentro de la pagina``
             </div>

              <div class="elementoOculto">
               ``` Este seria el Elemento que se va a mostrar cuando hagas alguna funcion con el mouse al hacerle click o cuando el mouse se sobrepone encima del elemento ``` 
              </div>
             <script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
````

````
            $().click('', function() {
                $('.ElementoOculto').show(); Con esta función muestras al hacerle click con Jquery o tal vez puedas usar un hover al posicionar sobre elemento y mostrarlo`, luego ``` para ocultar nuevamente si haces una función accediendo al elemento con un click haces la misma función para que al hacer click sobre los elementos de el body en cualquier parte este elemento se oculte. 
             })
         </script>
````

```css
           .elentoOculto {
            display: none;   // por defecto esta oculto 
            }
           .mostrarElemento {
              display: block;
            }
            .ElementoFlotante {
                display: fix; // siempre esta mostrando el elemento en una posición fixed
            position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                border-raidus: ;
            }
```

Este html, css y javascript no esta relacionado con los archivos del servidor solamente muestra una ventana que posiblemente cargue un html con el que se pueda colocar en interacción con el servidor. puedes usar socket para hacer el chat y comunicar al cliente con el servidor.

Comment: Hola kinslert, super bueno tu ejemplo lo tendre muy encuenta para mis futuros desarrollos , muy buen aporte,  pero mira lo que to trato de hacer es dejar solo un proyecto de un chtabot desarrollado en codeigniter 4 , unicamente el chat, y por ejemplo existen 3 paginas actualmente de diferentes personas que quieran ese chat , y las 3 paginas estan desarrolladas en diferente tecnologia ejemplo simfony, laravel , php puro, entonces tocaria desarrollar el bot en cada tecnologia y acoplarlo, mientras que con un referenciador del bot, se crea vista y se llama al script y traeria el bot sin instalar

Comment: Es justo lo que te expliqué no necesitas hacer una inclusión directa de otro script si vas a hacer referencia. ejemplo. tienes el html y en el html solo vas a tener la vista que se llama desde un controlador y en el controlador llamas a esa vista que dentro posee un par de eventos que pueden ser llamados con javascript y jquery. el archivo que se llama desde una etiqueta script es el que tendrá lo necesario para el cliente interactue desde esa vista. si quieres hacerlo puedes hacerlo haciendo uso de hooks y helpers que ya en muchos estan algunos en packageist puedes conseguir algunos ejemplos